# How can I print the Jsonarray in json-Glib?

Tags: c++, arrays, json, glib

I am using json-glib library. I have created one json array using that. I want to print that json array to see how it looks like. I mean that square brackets, commas and all, how they are included in json array. I have searched whole API but no function I have. I am using C++. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`json_generator_new`](https://developer.gnome.org/json-glib/stable/JsonGenerator.html#json-generator-new) and [`json_generator_to_data`](https://developer.gnome.org/json-glib/stable/JsonGenerator.html#json-generator-to-data).

```
void print_array (JsonArray *a)
{
    /* Setup root node and JSON generator */
    JsonNode *n = json_node_alloc();
    json_node_init_array(n, a);
    JsonGenerator *g = json_generator_new();
    json_generator_set_root(g, n);
    char *d = json_generator_to_data(g);

    /* Print JSON string */
    g_print("%s\n", d);

    /* Cleanup */
    g_free(d);
    g_unref(g);
    json_node_free(n);
}
```

Comment: but, that expect JsonBuilder* , but in my case, I have JsonArray but not the jsonBuilder. Please tell.

Comment: No, `JsonBuilder` is for reading JSON data. You need `JsonSerializer`, as stated in my answer.

Comment: Where have you mentioned about that Jsonserializer? Can you show a code snippet please? It would be of huge help.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `JsonGenerator`.

Comment: json_node_init_array and json_node_alloc is giving error. Saying: not declared in this scope. Please tell.